# By using cheerio is there a way to know if the attribute is with an initial value or not?

Tags: node.js, abstract-syntax-tree, cheerio

By using Cheerio is there a way to know if the attribute is with an initial value or not?

```
  <option value="" disabled selected>Please select</option>
  <option value disabled selected>Please select</option>
```

I try to select the option with value attribute, but the objects have values equal to an empty string:

```
doc("option[value]").each((i, el) => {
  const $el = doc(el);
  console.log({ a: doc(el).attr() });
});
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-darkness-d8reyj?file=/src/index.ts)